# How to move from a database backend to another on a production Django project?

Tags: django, database-migration

I would like to move a database in a Django project from a backend to another (in this case azure sql to postgresql, but I want to think of it as a generic situation). I can't use a dump since the databases are different.

I was thinking of something at the django level, like dumpdata, but depending on the amount of available memory and the size of the db sometimes it appears unreliable and crashes.

I have seen solutions that try to break the process into smaller parts that the memory can handle but it was a few years ago, so I was hoping to find other solutions.

So far my searches have failed since they always lead to 'south', which refers to schema migration and not moving data.

Answer (score 0):

I have not implemented this before, but what about the following:

Django supports multiple databases...so just configure DATABASES in your settings file to support the old postgresql database and the azure sql database.  Then create a small script that makes use of [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create), reading the data from one DB and writing it to the other.